# SubTitle for Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Does anybody know how to get a SubTitle bar in the navigation bar, like the NYTimes does (where they say Latest News). This is clearly part of the navigation bar since it stays still.  Here is what it looks like at the NYTimes (but a whole lot of other apps do the same).
http://cl.ly/362d181Q3l2I111q2Q46

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top part of your highlighted area (where it says "Latest News Updated moments ago") is a custom view that they have created and assigned to their table view's tableHeaderView property.

The bottom part of your highlighted area (where it says "Today") is a table section header.  Each section in a table gets an optional header.  They probably made theirs by implementing `– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` in their class implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol and returning the string @"Today" for that section.

Comment: Thanks..so if I wanted to do a  custom view only, do you happen to have an example of how that would assigned to the tableHeaderView property (I'm quite new at this, unfortunately).  Thanks.

Comment: If this answer is satisfactory, you should consider accepting it officially, so other people will know this question has an answer.